# search mutidimension arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like

```
$arr = array(
     array('contents' => "any value",
           'tags' => '<th>'
     ),

     array('contents' => "any value",
           'tags' => "<th>"

     )
     .
     .
     .
);
```

I want to echo the value of index "contents"

Comment: [Check the official php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Which "any value" are you trying to access?

Comment: I just want to echo all "any value" pls help.

Comment: Have you learned about *loops*? If not, go ahead and do.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the answers? If your problem is solved, I suggest that you accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use this (but you should check the docs to improve your knowledge about arrays):

```
$arr = array(
     array('contents' => "any value",
           'tags' => '<th>'
     ),

     array('contents' => "any value",
           'tags' => "<th>"

     )
);

foreach ($arr as $token){
    echo $token['contents'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$arr = array(array('contents' => "any value", "tags" => "<th>"),array('contents' => "any value","tags" => "<th>"));

    foreach($arr as $arrays){
        echo $arrays["contents"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) is quite useful for these kinds of things. It goes through each element of the array and applies a callback function:

```
array_walk($arr, function($x) { if (isset($x['contents'])) echo $x['contents']; });
```

Perhaps more simple, you could loop through the elements yourself:

```
foreach ($arr as $a) { 
    if (isset($a['contents'])) echo $a['contents']; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use something like

```
echo $arr["contents"]
```

To get the values you want...

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php